# Ionic 4 + Nodejs: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dgram' in

Tags: node.js, ionic3, angular-6

Estou criando um app usando o **ionic 4**.
Nesta aplicação preciso utilizar algumas bibliotecas do **Nodejs**: `dgram`, `fs`, `path` e dentre outras. Porém quando executo a minha aplicação, este retorna uma mensagem de erro

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dgram' in....
```

Isso acontece com todas as bibliotecas do **Nodejs**.

Em algumas pesquisas identifiquei que o **Ionic 4** não dar suporte para o **Nodejs**, uma vez que, o apk é criado com o plugin cordova.

> Nota: Também estou com esse problema no Framework do **angular 7**.

Alguém sabe informa se é possível resolver este problema?